# Harder investigation of a really strange unexpected result

Tags: c, io, bmp

I posted before about that problem.. but the problem couldn't be solved.
So i can honestly say that is the weirdest, unexplained complication i ever had in my programming experience.

The problem is when i draw a bmp from buffer.
[image]

If i change the image's dimension for example if i make width > height or height > width, the images goes rendered normally. Take a look at the code:

```
void bmp_bdraw (BYTE* BUFF)
{

    word WIDTH, HEIGHT, W, H; // word - unsigned short
    BYTE R, G, B; // BYTE - unsigned char

    (!BUFF || !BUFF[COUNT-1]) ? // debug1
        (error("Error in function 'bmp_bdraw'. There is no data to read from.")) : ;                  

    WIDTH = BUFF[18] + BUFF[19] * 256;
    HEIGHT = BUFF[22] + BUFF[23] * 256;
    ofs = 54;

    if(BUFF[0] != 'B' | BUFF[1] != 'M') error // debug2
        ("Warning: Data identifier error in function 'bmp_bdraw' occurred. Invalid BMP file loaded.");

    for(H=HEIGHT-1; H>=1; H--)
    {
        for(W=0; W<WIDTH; W++)
        {
            B = sgetc(BUFF); // fgetc-like function but from buff
            G = sgetc(BUFF);
            R = sgetc(BUFF);

            setpen(R, G, B, 0, 1); // sets the color, transparancy and size of the pen
            putpixel(W, H); // and puts the pixel at the right location
        }
    }

    if(W != WIDTH || H > 1) // debug3
        error("Error in function 'bmp_bdraw'. Rendering failed. The file might be damaged.");         

    if(real_fps < 11)
        error("Too low fps rate."); // debug4
```

What i have noticed in the line: `for(H=HEIGHT-1; H>=1; H--)` is the `H>=1`
In the direct draw (bmp to render) function (that works 100% and uses the same method) it is `H>=0`
However.. if i change the `H>=1` to `H>=0` it returns an error for buffer overflow, returned
by the `sgetc` function.

Comment: Very strange use of a ternary...

Comment: @Edenia: Why? You used `if` in the three other debug tests and there's no good reason to use that ridiculous ternary in the first one. By the way, you should use a logical OR `||` instead of that bitwise OR `|` in the debug2 test. Don't write sloppy code, it's harder to reason about and debug.

Comment: OT: Using `H>0` instead of `H>=1` is more clear.

Answer (score 2):

- <strike>Instead of putpixel prefer to use any bitblt function if available.</strike>
- Skip the [paddding bytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Pixel_storage) (if any) after the scan line has ended.

**Updated code**

```
numPadBytes = WIDTH * 3;
numPadBytes %= 4;
if(0 != numPadBytes) numPadBytes = 4 - numPadBytes;

for(H=HEIGHT-1; H>=1; H--)
{
 for(W=0; W<WIDTH; W++)
 {
  B = sgetc(BUFF); // fgetc-like function but from buff
  G = sgetc(BUFF);
  R = sgetc(BUFF);

  setpen(R, G, B, 0, 1); // sets the color, transparancy and size of the pen
  putpixel(W, H); // and puts the pixel at the right location
 }
 for(tmp = 0; tmp < numPadBytes; ++tmp)
 {
  /* Ignore bytes */
  sgetc(BUFF);
 }
}
```

You need to declare `numPadBytes` and `tmp` as `int` local to your function.

Comment: Sorry i can't use any other function but `putpixel`
That function works well everywhere. For example in the same function but for drawing FROM the bmp directly.
And what scan line you talk about?

Comment: Do you get correct output if the width of bmp is multiple of 4?

Comment: Tested one image with width that is not multiple of 4 and the result failed. But with one that is multiple of 4 the result is fine..
Which means it has something to do with the padding bytes yes but..I dont understand why.. why the direct draw function works well and that one not. Where is the difference.

Comment: But where is `tmp` declared?

Comment: You can declare it local to function. `int tmp;`

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop through the *stride* of the bitmap in the x direction.  Each row of a bitmap is padded to a multiple of four bytes.

Your code loops through the width (* 3 bytes), but there may be 1..3 extra bytes at the end of a row. The effect is that you starting drawing into the output buffer too early, skewing everything beyond the first row just a bit more to the left.

You can calculate the stride as follows.  Use that instead of the width.

```
int stride = 4 * ((width * bytesPerPixel + 3) / 4); // in bytes
```

So, reading the image data will look something like this...

```
unsigned char *scan0 = buf + pixel_buffer_offset;

for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
{
    // sets the pointer to the beginning of the yth row
    unsigned byte *row = scan0 + y * stride;

    for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
    { 
        unsigned char b = *row++;
        unsigned char g = *row++;
        unsigned char r = *row++;

        setpen(r, g, b, 0, 1);
        putpixel(x, y);
    }
}
```

whatever buffer you are writing to should be 0 initialized as we are not writing out the padding bytes.  If you don't want to do that then you will need to loop through the entire stride of each row.
 Also make sure that you have allocated `stride * height` bytes for it, not `width * height * 3`.

Comment: By `bytesPerPixel` do you mean `bitsPerPixel` ?
Use the stride instead of WIDTH in the loops ?
Why do i set pointer to the beginning of a row?
I am trying to figure out if your way is faster/shorter/better then the one by Mohit.

Comment: No, I mean bytes per pixel.  If you want to use bits per pixel then add 31 and divide by 32 (instead of 3 and 4).  Yes, you need to account for the stride in your loops for the reason that I mentioned.  Setting a pointer to the beginning of a row is just one way to read an image buffer. The pointer is that your loop is wrong because it fails to account for padding bytes at the end of a row.

Comment: I wish i could implement and test your way that does the thing without loops.. but it gives me one error
The first one is in the line:
`unsigned char *scan0 = BUFF[54];` saying that the pointer conversation is suspicious.

Comment: @Edenia: Sorry, I just wrote it off the top of my head, I didn't make a version that you could just drop in.  It's just an example. The pointer type should be `BYTE`.

Comment: yeah true.. i just started to fix them logically.
There is just one error left:
`BYTE *scan0 = BUFF[54];`
Wondering why it can't convert it.
I bet you meant `unsigned char *scan0 = &BUFF[54];` Thats not C++
Also did you purposely used a loop used to render the image flipped?
It renders it flipped anyway.. why is it flipped.
And why can't i JUST put something like `fseek(bmp, WIDTH%4, SEEK_CUR);` outside the inner loop.. that is what works to prevent the problem in the direct-draw function.

Comment: @Edenia: Sorry, my mistake. I've fixed it in the example.  Just add the offset to your buffer.  And no, I don't take the flip into account, but you know how to do that.

Comment: Its okay. I fixed that. Too tired to think of why the result is flipped though. I thought its because of the loop order.

Comment: It is. You need to start at the end of the buffer and loop backwards (exactly as your example code does...). Start at `y = height - 1` and then decrement y each iteration.

Comment: The thing is... i already changed the order correctly but the result is still flipped.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest something that involves only 1 line and causes no headaches:

```
ofs = ofs + WIDTH%4;
```

In the outer loop, after the inner loop. I just found out that works.. and i have no idea why people present so much code instead if doing this. Hope that helps if someone else decide to render from buffer.